# How to update a new json in old json in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, jsonb

this is my data which is available in the database.

```
INSERT INTO suppliers (id, "createdAt", "updatedAt", "userId", "fullName", email, phone, "profilePicture", "isEnabled", "role", "originDistrict", tln, "companyName", "companyAddress", "assignKam", "assignCluster", "vehicleProvide", "makePayout", "subsType", gender, status, "lookAtBid", "bidAccepted", "activeTrip", "isVerified") VALUES(36, '2022-02-21 18:46:01.527', '2022-09-12 13:20:31.132', '01FRJH5K6GV6KT4YP7RQ4H7N7K', 'syed musa tazim', NULL, '+8801696678835', NULL, false, 'vendor', '{"id": 46, "nameBn": "গাজীপুর", "nameEn": "Gazipur", "status": "active", "createdAt": "2021-12-31T18:08:40.056Z"}'::jsonb, NULL, 'Rofiqul Islam (GZP)', NULL, '{"role": "kam", "team": "vendor_team", "zone": "gazipur", "email": "tauhi15@loopfreight.io", "phone": "+8801721666512", "userId": "01GCDMQ7DS48XTCMT5JBYSS4NF", "fullName": "Mohammad Tareq"}'::jsonb, '{"role": "cluster_head", "zone": "gazipur", "email": "a28@gmail.com", "phone": "+8801328282828", "userId": "01GCNEE49Z3ZCBT73BK2BHVY6P", "fullName": "Iftikar Bhaia Gazipur"}'::jsonb, 20, 'monday'::public."suppliers_makepayout_enum", 'gold'::public."suppliers_substype_enum", 'male'::public."suppliers_gender_enum", 'inactive'::public."suppliers_status_enum", 0, 0, 0, false); INSERT INTO suppliers (id, "createdAt", "updatedAt", "userId", "fullName", email, phone, "profilePicture", "isEnabled", "role", "originDistrict", tln, "companyName", "companyAddress", "assignKam", "assignCluster", "vehicleProvide", "makePayout", "subsType", gender, status, "lookAtBid", "bidAccepted", "activeTrip", "isVerified") VALUES(143, '2022-07-14 10:39:36.397', '2023-01-11 16:03:26.445', '01G7XG2M1X1Y60H3W6GYBR2Q40', 'abcd', 'kamrul.islam@loopfreight.ios', '+8801828378263', NULL, true, 'vendor', '{"id": 46, "nameBn": "গাজীপুর", "nameEn": "Gazipur", "status": "active", "createdAt": "2021-12-31T18:08:40.056Z"}'::jsonb, NULL, 'Transport Agency (GZP)', 'abcd', '{"role": "kam", "team": "vendor_team", "zone": "gazipur", "email": "FoxVTNJ@test.com", "phone": "+8801312121215", "userId": "01GCB9NMCR0FVE7NTE825T06PF", "fullName": "A.B.M. Asaff-Ud-Daula"}'::jsonb, '{"role": "cluster_head", "zone": "gazipur", "email": "a28@gmail.com", "phone": "+8801328282828", "userId": "01GCNEE49Z3ZCBT73BK2BHVY6P", "fullName": "Iftikar Bhaia Gazipur"}'::jsonb, 50, 'wednesday'::public."suppliers_makepayout_enum", 'bronze'::public."suppliers_substype_enum", 'male'::public."suppliers_gender_enum", 'active'::public."suppliers_status_enum", 3, 0, 0, true); INSERT INTO suppliers (id, "createdAt", "updatedAt", "userId", "fullName", email, phone, "profilePicture", "isEnabled", "role", "originDistrict", tln, "companyName", "companyAddress", "assignKam", "assignCluster", "vehicleProvide", "makePayout", "subsType", gender, status, "lookAtBid", "bidAccepted", "activeTrip", "isVerified") VALUES(51, '2022-02-21 18:46:01.527', '2022-10-19 14:17:16.790', '01FV9WW0SZ58C3HX1XV8N6AKSR', 'some vendor 3 update yes', NULL, '+8801711223343', NULL, false, 'vendor', '{"id": 46, "nameBn": "গাজীপুর", "nameEn": "Gazipur", "status": "active", "createdAt": "2021-12-31T18:08:40.056Z"}'::jsonb, NULL, 'Matrichaya Transport Agency (GZP) yes', 'some vendor 3 company address', '{"role": "kam", "team": "vendor_team", "zone": "gazipur", "email": "tauhi15@loopfreight.io", "phone": "+8801721666512", "userId": "01GCDMQ7DS48XTCMT5JBYSS4NF", "fullName": "Mohammad Tareq"}'::jsonb, '{"role": "cluster_head", "zone": "gazipur", "email": "a28@gmail.com", "phone": "+8801328282828", "userId": "01GCNEE49Z3ZCBT73BK2BHVY6P", "fullName": "Bimol Das"}'::jsonb, 200, 'monday'::public."suppliers_makepayout_enum", 'gold'::public."suppliers_substype_enum", 'male'::public."suppliers_gender_enum", 'inactive'::public."suppliers_status_enum", 0, 0, 0, true); INSERT INTO suppliers (id, "createdAt", "updatedAt", "userId", "fullName", email, phone, "profilePicture", "isEnabled", "role", "originDistrict", tln, "companyName", "companyAddress", "assignKam", "assignCluster", "vehicleProvide", "makePayout", "subsType", gender, status, "lookAtBid", "bidAccepted", "activeTrip", "isVerified") VALUES(45, '2022-02-21 18:46:01.527', '2022-10-18 10:13:43.622', '01FSP5XNHEN9WH06Z320YSE416', 'tazim', NULL, '+8801676553344', NULL, false, 'vendor', '{"id": 46, "nameBn": "গাজীপুর", "nameEn": "Gazipur", "status": "active", "createdAt": "2021-12-31T18:08:40.056Z"}'::jsonb, NULL, 'Md. Parvez Alam (GZP)', 'h-747, road-08 ,Adabor ,Dhaka', '{"role": "kam", "team": "vendor_team", "zone": "gazipur", "email": "tauhi15@loopfreight.io", "phone": "+8801721666512", "userId": "01GCDMQ7DS48XTCMT5JBYSS4NF", "fullName": "Mohammad Tareq"}'::jsonb, '{"role": "cluster_head", "zone": "gazipur", "email": "a28@gmail.com", "phone": "+8801328282828", "userId": "01GCNEE49Z3ZCBT73BK2BHVY6P", "fullName": "Iftikar Bhaia Gazipur"}'::jsonb, 12, 'monday'::public."suppliers_makepayout_enum", 'tin'::public."suppliers_substype_enum", 'male'::public."suppliers_gender_enum", 'inactive'::public."suppliers_status_enum", 0, 0, 0, false); INSERT INTO suppliers (id, "createdAt", "updatedAt", "userId", "fullName", email, phone, "profilePicture", "isEnabled", "role", "originDistrict", tln, "companyName", "companyAddress", "assignKam", "assignCluster", "vehicleProvide", "makePayout", "subsType", gender, status, "lookAtBid", "bidAccepted", "activeTrip", "isVerified") VALUES(138, '2022-07-06 13:33:43.305', '2023-01-11 16:33:44.418', '01G796VP5GZWBM90BSXSB5QE6A', 'testing vendor fullname 5', NULL, '+8801345454545', NULL, true, 'vendor', '{"id": 46, "nameBn": "গাজীপুর", "nameEn": "Gazipur", "status": "active", "createdAt": "2021-12-31T18:08:40.056Z"}'::jsonb, NULL, 'Connect Transport Agency (GZP)', 'tesiting vendor address', '{"role": "kam", "team": "vendor_team", "zone": "gazipur", "email": "FoxVTNJ@test.com", "phone": "+8801312121215", "userId": "01GCB9NMCR0FVE7NTE825T06PF", "fullName": "A.B.M. Asaff-Ud-Daula"}'::jsonb, '{"role": "cluster_head", "zone": "gazipur", "email": "a28@gmail.com", "phone": "+8801328282828", "userId": "01GCNEE49Z3ZCBT73BK2BHVY6P", "fullName": "Iftikar Bhaia Gazipur"}'::jsonb, 0, 'wednesday'::public."suppliers_makepayout_enum", 'gold'::public."suppliers_substype_enum", 'male'::public."suppliers_gender_enum", 'active'::public."suppliers_status_enum", 14, 0, 1, true);
```

I want to replace this

```
{"role": "cluster_head", "zone": "gazipur", "email": "a28@gmail.com", "phone": "+8801328282828", "userId": "01GCNEE49Z3ZCBT73BK2BHVY6P", "fullName": "Iftikar Bhaia Gazipur"}
```

with

```
{userId: '01GBSDPSCAE74FVCK2XPPCRDYH',profilePicture: 'https://dev-cdn.loopfreight.io/public/cd4a89cae5d4516efabf73ccd774583e.jpg',fullName: 'Rayhan Zaman',isEnabled: true,isVerified: true,designation: 'Manager ',department: 'operation',zone: 'khulna',phone: '+8801811111111',email: 'rayhan@gmail.com',createdAt: '2022-08-31T07:44:00.905Z',gender: 'male',role: 'cluster_head'}
```

how can I change it?

I will get the 2nd json from another service. So I want to replace it.
I have tried like this

```
update suppliers set "assignCluster" = jsonb_set({userId: '01GBSDPSCAE74FVCK2XPPCRDYH',profilePicture: 'https://dev-cdn.loopfreight.io/public/cd4a89cae5d4516efabf73ccd774583e.jpg',fullName: 'Rayhan Zaman',isEnabled: true,isVerified: true,designation: 'Manager ',department: 'operation',zone: 'khulna',phone: '+8801811111111',email: 'rayhan@gmail.com',createdAt: '2022-08-31T07:44:00.905Z',gender: 'male',role: 'cluster_head'})::jsonb where "assignCluster"->>"userId" = '01GBSDPSCAE74FVCK2XPPCRDYH';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `jsonb_set`. You want to replace the entire value of the column, not manipulate some JSON.
Also you need to put the JSON value in an SQL literal, and properly quote property names and strings in it.

```
update suppliers
set "assignCluster" = '{"userId": "01GBSDPSCAE74FVCK2XPPCRDYH", "profilePicture": "https://dev-cdn.loopfreight.io/public/cd4a89cae5d4516efabf73ccd774583e.jpg", "fullName": "Rayhan Zaman", "isEnabled": true, "isVerified": true, "designation": "Manager", "department": "operation", "zone": "khulna", "phone": "+8801811111111", "email": "rayhan@gmail.com", "createdAt": "2022-08-31T07:44:00.905Z", "gender": "male", "role": "cluster_head"}'
where "assignCluster"->>'userId' = '01GBSDPSCAE74FVCK2XPPCRDYH';
```